# How do you create a plugin in jQuery that passes variables back like the 'load' function?

Tags: jquery

The load function in jQuery allows for information to come back via last parameter.  How do you do this when creating a custom plugin?  I know I can do a 'onComplete' (or whatever) function but I was wondering how to do it like 'load'  does.

Example 'load'

```
$("#div").load('{url}', { vars:true }, function(response){
   // do something
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8RTz6/

I'm assuming that you know how to create a jQuery plugin so I'm gonna proceed with explaining the callback function of the custom plugin.

Here is the sample plugin that I use as an example, this plugin replaces the html (text) of an element and adds a class to it:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myOwnPlugin = function (options, myOwnCallback) {
        var defaults = {
            msg: "This is the default message",
            class: "myOwnPlugin-class"
        }
        if (typeof myOwnCallback == 'function') {
            var ot = this.html();
            myOwnCallback.call(this, {originalText: ot});

        }

        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        this.html(settings.msg);
        this.addClass(settings.class);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

You would have that in a `.js` file and you woiuld include it in your html using the `script` tag

This is how you can call the function of the plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test").myOwnPlugin({msg: "This is a test."}, function(response){
        console.log(response.originalText);
    });
});
```

Now to explain whats going on, you are adding a parameter to the main function `myOwnPlugin` the parameter is called `myOwnCallback` then we check that its a function type and if it is we change the scope to that function using `.call` then you can attach anything to that function as a response by adding an object i.e `{originalText: ot, somethingElse: value, .... }`

I hope that makes sense, see the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8RTz6/

Answer (score 0):

do you mean applying a method as the call back? ex:

```
$("#div").load('{url}', { vars:true }, function(){
   $(this).myCustomJqueryMethod(); // plugin
});
```